# Python Regex to find first word after a word

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I am new to regex. 
So I apologize for asking, if this is a stupid question.
I have a long string (see below)

```
If you require further assistance please contact us by sending email to
export@cisco.com.

Cisco                 7206VXR (NPE400) processor (revision A) with 491520K/32768K bytes of memory.
Processor board ID 4279256517
R7000 CPU at 150MHz, Implementation 39, Rev 2.1, 256KB L2 Cache
6 slot VXR midplane, Version 2.1
```

I am trying to extract the substring "7206VXR".
I have found a working solutions to the problem after checking from here
https://regex101.com/
Solution 1 is

```
re.search(r"Cisco((\s*)(\w*).*)(bytes of memory)
uptime = hostUptimeRegex.group(3)
print "hostUptimeRegex.group(3) is :" + uptime + ":"
```

[image]
What I would just like to know is, is there a **better** way to

> find the ***first "word"*** (i.e. a series of alpha numeric characters surrounded on both sides by whitespace) in the sentence that starts with the word "Cisco" and ends with "bytes of memory."

Comment: `Cisco\s*(\w+)(?=.*bytes of memory)`?

Comment: Is what you're looking for always the first non-whitespace string after "Cisco"?

Comment: @ ctwheels Thanks! That was helpful!
@CAustin Hi yes, for this scenario. But there is another scenario where I want to select all non-white spaces (i.e words) after "Cisco" and before "bytes of memory" Thanks for your help as well!

Comment: Instead of `\s*` use `\s+` since you need at least one space. Also, using a lookahead is useless since you use the `re.search` method that only returns capture groups if any. `Cisco\s+(\w+)\s.*bytes of memory`. Eventually use the `re.DOTALL` flag.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thanks! I have just 1 more question. How can I select all non-white spaces (i.e words) after "Cisco" and before "bytes of memory"?

Comment: `Cisco\s+(.+?)\s+bytes of memory`. Then you have to split the result.

Comment: Or using the [pypi regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex), you can use the repeated capture group feature with this pattern: `Cisco\s+(?:(\S+)\s+)*?bytes of memory` (see the doc)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
import re
text = r"""If you require further assistance please contact us by sending email to
export@cisco.com.

Cisco                 7206VXR (NPE400) processor (revision A) with 491520K/32768K bytes of memory.
Processor board ID 4279256517
R7000 CPU at 150MHz, Implementation 39, Rev 2.1, 256KB L2 Cache
6 slot VXR midplane, Version 2.1"""

# Get 7206VXR
match = re.search(r'(?<!\S)Cisco\s+([A-Za-z0-9]+)(?=.*\bbytes\s+of\s+memory\b)', text)
if match:
    print(match.group(1)) # => 7206VXR

# Get all non-whitespace chunks between Cisco and bytes of memory
match = re.search(r'(?<!\S)Cisco(?=\s)(.*?)\s*\bbytes\s+of\s+memory\b', text)
if match:
    print(match.group(1).split())
# => ['7206VXR', '(NPE400)', 'processor', '(revision', 'A)', 'with', '491520K/32768K']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ypxgg9).

*Details*:

- `(?<!\S)` - a left-hand whitespace boundary
- `Cisco` - a fixed string
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `([A-Za-z0-9]+)` - Group 1: one or more ASCII alphanumerics
- `(?=\s)(.*?)\s*` (in another pattern): the next char must be a whitespace, then Group 1 capturing any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible, and then zero or more whitespaces
- `(?=.*\bbytes\s+of\s+memory\b)` - a positive lookahead that requires the following patterns immediately to the right of the current location:

  - `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
  - `\b` - a word boundary
  - `bytes\s+of\s+memory` - `bytes of memory` with any one or more whitespaces between the words
  - `\b` - a word boundary.

See [regex #1](https://regex101.com/r/cDiwID/1) and [regex #2 demos](https://regex101.com/r/cDiwID/2).